# Hide play button in video tag in HTML5 in firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, video

I have my own custom play button for video, and I want to hide default play button

check here [VIDEO TAG LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)

I tried `.tp-video-play-button {display: none !important}`

and removing controls attribute is hiding all other controls like progress bar and volume buttons

but it is not working.

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `controls` from the following line:

```
<video width="400" controls>
```

Comment: No, it will hide all controls like progress bar and volume also

Comment: it's all or nothing with the controls. if you want to replace an element then you'll need to do everything